# Jubula problems with "perform login" and login unassigned component names

Tags: java, testing, jubula

Using Jubula standalone version 8.3.0.122 on Linux, I've run into a pair of related problems:

1. The "errors" section in the "Problems" view gave me two messages about `Incomplete Test Data for node "Perform login"`.  This would happen even with freshly created projects as soon as I did anything to modify the project, even changing the project description.
2. In object mapping mode there were three unassigned component names `login_login_btn`, `login_password_txf` and `login_username_txf`. This would happen even though I'd used no names even slightly similar, and would happen regardless of the AUT being used.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the "project template" that's included by default in new projects.  There's two different solutions:

1. Start a brand new project via menu item *Test > New*, but uncheck `Load project template` before pressing `Finish`.
2. In an old project, first delete the test suites `INCUBATION`, `PRODUCTIVE`, and `WORK`, then delete all of the default test case groups besides `unbound_modules_concrete` (that is, `00 - Application Test Cases` through `03 - Work`).